# MySQLi - numrows query issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

been having a little bit of an issue with mysqli_num_rows.

The query is designed to check that the user has username entries in the database and allow them to continue with the configuration if true.

my query is:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('../connection.php');    
$sessthis = session_id();
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `session_id`='$sessthis'");
mysqli_store_result($con);
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0)
{
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
?>
```

The problem is that it just keeps giving a false result and redirecting back - I have 5 results entered in so it shouldnt fail, even fails when I removed WHERE...

I would much appreciate any help someone can offer.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$row_cnt = $query->num_rows;
if ($row_cnt == 0)
{
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, got it working, turns out that the include should have been includes/connection.php - many thanks though, shall be using your version of the query.